# What do I have to change about my activity to integrate Swipe View?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, webview

So this is what my current activity looks like:

```
package com.example;

import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class TestActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);

        // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
        AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this); // Add this method.
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this); // Add this method.
    }
}
```

My layout file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1596992408570157/3380743224" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:src="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Currency: Afghan Afghani" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I would like to add a page that consists of a single webview. I want the user to be able to swipe from this activity to that activity (the one with the webview). I'm having a lot of problems figuring out how to implement the swipeviews. Does anyone know what I have to add/change about my current layout/activity file to get the swipe view with webview to work? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use ViewPager and your activity must extend FragmentActivity. Look at this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html).

Comment: Could you give me a rough reworking/refactoring of my code that I can build off of? I'm more of a visual learner.

Comment: I've looked through the Android docs for the ViewPager before and it made no sense.